# Django mange.py migrate --> No Migration folder and no tables created

Tags: python, django, migration

I recently started to experiment with python and Django at the same time. After playing with several little projects from GitHub and or youtube and tried do it from scratch now on my own.

My problem is, the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Only creates those 10 "standard" Django and "auth" tables in my local mysql db.

Attached you can find my project structure. The way I started was with " django-admin startproject Nico".

[image]

Then step after step've created models, views, forms and templates.

My best guess is, the migrate command does not find the models file.
But I don't know where to specify that. At least that is a missing link. In my previous examples which were complete, I never had to declare that. Would that go in the right direction?

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from ReProg.ReProg.models import Kunde
from ReProg.ReProg.forms import KundeForm

class HP(TemplateView):
    Model = Kunde
    Form = KundeForm
    #template_name = "TestViewHello.html"
    #template_name = "KundenAufnahme.html"
    template_name = "KundenAufnahme2.html"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import render
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit


class KundeForm(forms.Form):
    #KID = forms.CharField(attrs={'disabled': True})
    KID = forms.CharField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ReProg'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Wilhelm'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '123@Mail.com'}))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KundeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from datetime import date


###########Kunde
class Kunde(models.Model):
    KID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
def KID(key):
    num = Request.objects.all().count()
    return K + str(num)

class KundeMF(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Kunde
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'KID']
```

settings.py

```
Django settings for ReProg project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+e69jgm56u85imt)(=6@82@c60222e9-z0+h8b+kxwhe(kc*z4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ReProg',
    'crispy_forms',
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ReProg.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ReProg.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ReProg',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Before running `migrate` you need to run `makemigrations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `python manage.py makemigrations <app name>`
2. `python manage.py migrate <app name>`

Comment: Cool, the add on with <app name> resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

first make the following

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

if the problem did not solved make the following:

1- If the folder **migrations** did not found in the app directory create it.

2- If the folder found check the `__init__.py` file inside the folder.
if this file did not found create new file with name `__init__.py`.

Comment: the solution from 0k4 with adding the <app name> resolved it

Answer (score 0):

it worked with adding the

i forgot to mention that before migrating I executed "makemigrations".
However it said "no changes detected" or something similar.

Now with the  it works. I can see the table now in mysql.
[enter image description here][1]

thx all
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaKFg.png